# Calculate limit inferior and limit superior of $v_{n}$.

Tags: limits, limsup-and-liminf

Let us consider a positive and bounded real sequence $(u_{n})$. Let $a,b$ be two positive real numbers. Assuming that there exists $N$ such for all $n>N$ we have $u_{n}>0$, define the new sequence:

$$v_{n}=\log(a+bu_{n})/u_{n}$$  for all $n>N$.

I am asking about the necessary steps to calculate limit inferior and limit superior of $(v_{n})$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I don't think theres an explicit way given what we know. If $L$ is a partial limit of $(u_n)$ achieved by a subsequence $(u_{n_k})$, then we can create a subsequence $(v_{n_k}=\frac{\log(a+bu_{n_k})}{u_{n_k}})$ of $(v_n)$ which approaches to $f(L):=\frac{\log(a+bL)}{L}$ by arithmetics. since $f$ is always monotonic on $(0,\infty)$, the corrospondence is bijective, meaning two partial limits of $(u_n)$ can't mix, and that any partial limit of $f(u_n)$ must come from a unique partial limit of $(u_n)$.

If so we can charecterize the partial limits of $f(u_n)$ by
$$\left \{ f(L) | L\  \text{is a partial limit of}\ (u_n) \right \}$$
and we need to find its $\inf,\sup$. Note that this includes the special case of a partial limit $0$ which yields a partial limit of $-\infty/\infty/1$ depending on $a,b$.

Comment: You mean the $inf$ and $sup$ of the last set of your answer.

Comment: Yup (technically, remember that the set needs to be bounded to discuss the sup and inf, so the case of $0$ might break it), finding them of course depends alot on $(u_n)$ which is the reason for the amorphic answer @Safwane

Comment: The fact that $u_{n}$ is bounded, i.e., $w<u_{n}<u$ and $f$ is increasing for some $a,b>0$ implies that $L=u$.

Comment: How so? for example $0<1-\frac{1}{n}<2$ is bounded but that doesn't mean $L=2$. $f$ doesn't have anything to do with convergence of $(u_n)$ in my opinion @Safwane